# Unable to change brightness on fedora 31

Tags: fedora, nvidia, laptop, brightness

I recently bought a Lenovo y7000. I have installed fedora 31 and configured the nvidia drivers for it also. Everything works fine but my brightness is stuck at maximum.

I cannot change it via the slider that fedora provides or via the `fn` keys. 
I have tried multiple solutions for this:

- Added `acpi_backlight=vendor` to my GRUB file and rebooted. (Yes, I updated the grub before rebooting)
- Manually changed the `/sys/class/backlight/ideapad/*` files, which did not have any effect. Changing via the slider also changes the value in these files but there is no effect seen in the brightness.
- Installed `xbacklight` and tried to change brightness via it.

I am adding my laptop details

```
~ neofetch

 --------------------------- 
 OS: Fedora 31 (Workstation Edition) x86_64 
 Host: 81T0 Lenovo Legion Y7000 2019 PG0 
 Kernel: 5.3.16-300.fc31.x86_64 
 Uptime: 22 mins 
 Packages: 1784 (rpm) 
 Shell: bash 5.0.11 
 Resolution: 1920x1080 
 DE: GNOME 3.34.2 
 WM: Mutter 
 WM Theme: Adwaita 
 Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
 Icons: Adwaita [GTK2/3] 
 Terminal: deepin-terminal 
 Terminal Font: Source Code Pro Semibold 10 
 CPU: Intel i7-9750H (12) @ 4.500GHz 
 GPU: NVIDIA 01:00.0 NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f91
 Memory: 2940MiB / 32035MiB
```

Is there any other way this can be fixed?